# Google map fragment within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, maps

Followed a tutorial to work with Google Maps and it works well. Now I'd like to have this map placed within a fragment for a `TableLayout` and can't figure out how to change the code for `SupportFragmentManager` (which drops an error). I get "UNREACHABLE CODE" when I replace it with `childFragmentManager`.

Here is my code:

```
class FragItLocate : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker?)=false

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_it_locate,container,false)

        val mapFragment = childFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map2) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
        mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
        // Add a marker in Atlantic Lawn and Garden and move the camera
        val alg = LatLng(41.4958611, -71.3768593)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(alg).title("Atlantic Lawn and Garden"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(alg))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(alg, 17.05f))


    }
}
```

**Update:** I've tried the answer but my app crash with this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdmKT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you call this line

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_it_locate, container, false)
```

it will exit `onCreateView` method and do not execute all statements after that line. That why your get `UNREACHABLE CODE` error.

So change your code to

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
      val mapFragment = childFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map2) as SupportMapFragment
      mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_it_locate, container, false);
}
```

**Update:** You got that error because this line.

```
val mapFragment = childFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map2) as SupportMapFragment
```

If `findFragmentById(R.id.map2)` return `null`, your app will crash because you are using `Unsafe Cast` operator.

You can prevent that by using `Smart Cast` operator.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
      val mapFragment = childFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map2) as SupportMapFragment?
      mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)

      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_it_locate, container, false);
}
```

**Update 2:** Based on your comment about `onMapReady` not called.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val mapFragment = childFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map2) as SupportMapFragment?

    if (mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map2, mapFragment).commit();
    }

    mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_it_locate, container, false);
}
```

Comment: now I've noticed that moving to the bottom of the function this line:
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_it_locate, container, false);
works just one time. When relaunching the app it will cause a typecasting non-null exception. Probably has something to do with the inflater. Any ideas?

Comment: Added the screenshot. Line 27 is .findFragmentById(R.id.map2) as SupportMapFragment

Comment: the error is solved, map is displayed but now the problem is that when app is relaunched it doesn't seem to load the  onMapReady function

Comment: Now it fully works! I only had to change the constant to var mapFragment